# SQL query to fetch records from second table with minimum final price value

Tags: sql, mariadb

How to fetch SQL query to fetch records from the second table with minimum final price value.

**Catalog_Product** Table,

| sku | entity_id |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| def | 2 |
| pqr | 3 |

**Catalog_Product_Price** Table,

| price | entity_id | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | default |
| 5 | 1 | us |
| 17 | 1 | uk |
| 20 | 2 | default |
| 30 | 2 | uk |
| 50 | 3 | default |
| 50 | 3 | us |

I want results like fetching minimum price records with all the columns from the second table,

**Catalog_Product_Price** Table,

| sku | entity_id | price | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 5 | us |
| def | 2 | 20 | default |
| pqr | 3 | 50 | default |

I have tried SQL query,

```
SELECT c.sku, cp.*, min(cp.final_price) FROM `Catalog_Product` as c inner join Catalog_Product_Price as cp on cp.entity_id = c.entity_id group by c.entity_id;
```

But it's not working as expected. How to fetch records with a second table with a minimum price column.

Here response will be always the first match rows instead of minimum price value.

Are there any mistakes in the SQL query to fetch results as per the above solutions?

Comment: *But its not working* is not an error description. Please explain what it means

Comment: Its not result as per expectation and always result the first matched row instead of lowest price records.

Comment: WHich version of MySql?

Comment: Mariadb 10.3 version.

Comment: Use a windows function `row_number()`

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya For the ties on price, do you want it to select one randomly or is there a tie-break rule?

Comment: @Error_2646 I want lowest price records and if both records have same price, fetch first one.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya "First" by what definition? First only means something if you have an order by.

Comment: You have written comments that you use MariaDB 10.3, but you also ask about MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8.0. Please be clear about which brand and version you are using. The best solutions may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the capability of `ROW_NUMBER()` function in version `5.7`. We can of course emulate the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Something like:

```sql
SELECT cp.sku, cpp1.entity_id, cpp1.price, cpp1.code
FROM Catalog_Product cp
JOIN (
  SELECT cpp.entity_id, cpp.price, cpp.code, 
         @row_number:=CASE
            WHEN @entity_id = cpp.entity_id THEN @row_number + 1
            ELSE 1
         END AS rn,
         @entity_id:=cpp.entity_id
  FROM Catalog_Product_Price cpp,
  (SELECT @row_number:=0, @entity_id:='') vars
  ORDER BY cpp.entity_id, cpp.price
) cpp1 ON cp.entity_id = cpp1.entity_id
WHERE cpp1.rn = 1;
```

**Query Result:**

```bash
# sku      entity_id        price   code
# abc         1              5       us
# def         2              20      default
# pqr         3              50      default
```

**EDIT:** The above query will work for any version of MySQL. But of course if you're using `MySQL version 8` consider using `ROW_NUMBER()` as mentioned in another answer.

***[DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oUt1mDhWyPHw8WRL3q95SN/0)***

Comment: This will missing the sku with pqr result records. If more than one records available to second table, its working fine but for single record like SKU pqr not working.

Comment: Please check my updated table in the post, if ID 3 has the same price, it will display two records instead of single one.

Comment: How to do it with mysql 8? Your query is working fine except when same price available in second table with entity id, its duplicated on final result.

Comment: This is still not working when you have id 3 with the code field value the same as default. it results in all two records. –

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a version supporting window functions (`mysql 8`/mariadb 10.2 or higher) then you can use `row_number()` to order records by price per entity.

You can also use `rank()` instead of `row_number()` if you have ties and you want to return them all (exemple two product with same lowest price).

```
select sku, entity_id, price, code
from (
  select sku, cpp.*, row_number() over (partition by cpp.entity_id order by cpp.price) as rn
  from Catalog_Product_Price cpp
  inner join Catalog_Product cp on cp.entity_id = cpp.entity_id
) as s
where rn = 1;
```

Results :

```
sku entity_id   price   code
abc 1           5       us
def 2           20      default
pqr 3           50      default
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/U35q0Vwt)

Comment: Could you please give me solutions for the MySQL version? The above solutions is not working for me.

Comment: Which version of MySQL you are using ?

Comment: Mysql version 5.7

Comment: Could you please update your answer without using of row_number() and rank()?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya You can research `row_number` alternative for MySql 5.7. It's not as pretty but is possible. There should be solutions on SO for it.